# Error: expected unqualified-id before '&' token

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a uni assignment and in it we create Task objects and assign successor and predecessor Tasks to each to chain them together. When I try to return a successor or predecessor, I keep getting this error (as in the title)
Here's the Task.h relevant sections:

```
class Task {
private:    
/**
 * The set of predecessor tasks for this task.
 * Can be empty.
 */
std::vector<Task*> task_from;
/**
 * The set of successor tasks for this task.
 * Can be empty.
 */
std::vector<Task*> task_to;
```

Here is the Task.cpp file relevant sections (method pulls Task out of array at given index):

```
Task& Task::successor(int index) const {
    if (index < 0) throw TaskException("");
    Task temp = this->&task_to.at(index);
    return temp;
}
```

Note that the method signatures are pre-defined for the assignment and we can't change them, just the code inside the braces is ours to write.

Also, if I don't include the '&' in this->&task..., I get the error "Types 'Task' and 'Task*' are not compatible"

Comment: You're returning a reference to a temporary, don't do that

Comment: What's a better way to do this, then? 
I'm new to C++ and that's how I did it with my Java courses so far and it's worked there. 
I also get the same error if I do a straight 'return this->&task_to.at etc'

Comment: Maybe in Java it did, but here you are allocating temp on stack - memory which can and probably will be overwritten after the function returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return a function-local variable by reference, which will leave you with a dangling reference as soon as you return from the function.  If you are trying to get a reference to the `Task` in your `vector`, your `successor` function would look like

```
Task& Task::successor(int index) const {
    if (index < 0) throw TaskException("");
    return *task_to.at(index);
}
```

Know that this does not check that the `Task*` at that index is not `nullptr`.

Comment: Perfect! This fixed the problem. Thank you so much. Man, this is so different from java. Haha.

Comment: Notably the * is dereferencing the existing pointer, and then it is automatically converted to a reference when returned.

Comment: @Neofish converted ? Dereferencing a pointer yields a reference already.

Comment: @Quentin is correct, the [syntax for the indirection operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) is `R& T::operator*();` it is defined to return a reference

Comment: Yeah that does make entirely more sense, sorry for confusing things. My intention was just to add to the explanation.

Perhaps more important is the question's error is related to the `->&`, not returning a ref to a temporary (which would have been a problem if the statement was meaningful).